# Copy rectangle text into org-table

Tags: rectangle

I have 5 rows of text:

```
1   0%
2   от 1% до 20%
3   от 21% до 50%
4   от 51% до 100%
5   100%
```

And I would like to copy everything after digits (1..5) to a table column `PRC`

```
| N | PRC|
|   |    |
|   |    |
|   |    |
|   |    |
|   |    |
```

I have tried different rectangle commands but was unable to select correct rectangle from 0% to 100% -- I only got part of text.

Comment: I would try to convert the text into org-tables first, then it's way easier to copy from an org-table rectangular regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using your data, and the normal `C-x r` rectangle commands work just fine?

I marked the corners (adding the necessary spaces) and copied the rectangle with `C-x r M-w` and then yanked it into the table column (with point in the first data row for that column) with `C-x r y` (and `TAB` to tidy up the column lines).

edit: In fact, *all* the rectangle editing options I know of work fine here.

In addition to the above, I can mark the rectangle with `C-x SPC`, copy with `M-w`, and yank into the column with `C-y`; and the same copy/yank works for `cua-selection-mode`'s rectangle editing.

This is in Emacs 24.5.1 with Org 8.2.10

Comment: Well I am old vim user and there is a way in vim to easily mark rectangles without adding spaces. I thought there should be smth similar in emacs.

Comment: So is this (adding spaces) a proper emacs way of rectangular manipulations?

Comment: For some approaches, yes. It sounds like you'd like the `cua` rectangle editing, though; that doesn't require additional space characters to be added. You can use `(cua-selection-mode 1)` to enable it permanently. Read `M-x find-library RET cua-base RET` for documentation -- look for "rectangle" in the commentary.

Comment: Alternatively (and I forget exactly where I first read this), you can also use `artist-mode` as a trick to avoid entering spaces while marking rectangles. It wouldn't surprise me if someone has written a convenience library to make that convenient to use in practice.